# Call one Razor helper from another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to create the second overload of Razor helper and want to call one helper from another (with some specific parameters).  Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class ActionLinkExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        // call the base ActionLink helper:
        return html.ActionLink("some text", "someAction");
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.MyActionLink()
```

If you are talking about `@helper` Razor helpers you need to pass an instance of the `HtmlHelper` as argument because it is not available in the helper context:

```
@helper MyActionLink(HtmlHelper html)
{
    @html.ActionLink("some text", "someAction")
}
```

and then:

```
@MyActionLink(Html)
```

Personally I prefer the first approach as it is view engine agnostic and can be ported across any other view engines you like whereas the second is Razor specific and if tomorrow Microsoft invent the Blade view engine you will have to rewrite much of your code.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot @ before inner helper call :(

Comment: @Idsa, glad you could make it work? Are there still some other issues or maybe you could consider closing this thread?

Comment: sorry I was out of computer for a while

Comment: @Darin one kind help. is it posssible call one helper from one view to another view